# Binding objects from spring multiple <form:select>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, collections

Have to beans:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="book")
    public class Book {
        @Id
        @Column(name="id_book")
        @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
        private int id;

        @Column
        @Size(min=1,max=100)
        private String title;

        @Column 
        @Size(min=1,max=400)
        private String description;


        @Column
        private Integer year=0;

        @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)
        @JoinTable(name="book_author", 
                 joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="book_id_book")}, 
                     inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="author_id_author")})
        private List<Author> author=new ArrayList<Author>();

       //getters/setters
   }
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_author")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;


@Column
private String name;


@Column
private String surname;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="author")
private Set<Book> book=new HashSet<Book>();

    //getters/setters
}
```

In my jsp I'm have form for enter data about book, and multiple list for select author(s) from DB, problem only in select authors, therefore give only this code:

```
<sf:select multiple="true" path="author" items="${authors}" size="7" >
</sf:select>
```

Where ${authors} - List with objects Author from DB. Use POST request.

In my controller for this page have this (I know it's not correct):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addbook", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBook(Book book){
        hibarnateService.saveBook(book);
        return "redirect:/books";
    }
```

When I'm create book without select authors, but enter another information, all fine, book save in DB. When select some authors get this - `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by add in controller:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Author.class, new Editor(hibarnateService));
}
```

and create class:

```
public class Editor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private final Dao hibernateService;

    public Editor(Dao hibernateService){
        this.hibernateService=hibernateService;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        Author author=hibernateService.getAuthor(Integer.parseInt(text));
        setValue(author);
    }
}
```

P.S. What wrong with me? I can't find the right answer myself until I ask here)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement initBinder in your controller, below can be tentative code (not tested)

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "authors ", new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class)
          {
            @Override
            protected Object convertElement(Object element)
            {
                Long id = null;

                if(element instanceof Long) {
                    //From the database 'element' will be a Long
                    id = (Long) element;
                }

                return id != null ? authorService.loadAuthorById(id) : null;
            }
          });
    }
```

Comment: try add this, corrected for my example. But have same result `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect`

Comment: have you checked your init binder is getting invoked when you select author?